# Separate EFI partitions per disk?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, bootloader, grub-efi

I am trying to dual boot Linux and Windows on a system with 2 different hard drives, drive C has Windows 10 installed and drive D Linux (Arch in my case).
I'm now wondering whether I should have a separate EFI partitions on both disks or should I only have an EFI partition on my C drive and install my bootloader for Linux there?
Some time ago I installed Debian as dual boot and apparently the installer made a new EFI partition on D (which I forgot to delete afterwards so it's still there).

So my question: Where should I install my Linux bootloader (and which one, as I hear GRUB doesn't really support dual boot with Windows)?

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask **Ubuntu**. Instead your question may fit on [Unix.SE] or more generally [SU].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the second drive to be bootable it has to have an efi partition. However, it is not necessary if you only boot from the first drive. Grub fully supports dual booting with windows, but some machines make you do a few tweaks (moving some files around)to keep windows from putting itself back in the first boot slot.

PS: I would make both disks bootable. that way if something does happen to disk one, you can still boot from disk two to do repairs.just install grub to the efi partition of both disks.

Comment: Is there a difference in the installation for GRUB on D (empty EFP) and C (already containing Windows bootloader)?

Comment: is D a removable drive? if it is then /efi/ubuntu/grubx64 needs to be copied to /efi/boot/bootx64.efi. now the trick for C: if after running windows you find that you don't get grub again, yo have to do the same onn drive C replacing the windows loader with grubs (it must be renamed to bootx64.efi). if you are using secure boot the file might be shimx64.efi

Comment: I'm just having a little issues overwriting the windows bootloader, as one day I might go back to mono booting windows again, won't that be a problem then? Would there not be a possebility to use the windows bootloader to load GRUB?

PS: D is not a removable drive

Comment: you might still have to do the move, I'm not sure how your system will handle a second internal. some older system you have to do it to drive C also as they can not record an OS until it is booted from /efi/boot/bootx64.efi

Comment: windows will not load grub. just move the windows loader to the efi/windows/ folder. there is probably a copy in their already. try booting first before moving the files. it isn't necessary on a computer wit a good efi implementation.